# Custom report without using collection

Tags: magento2.2, array, custom-reports

I have a request which to make custom report, and data for the report need to calculate by helper function and will generate a data array with row and columns.

Is there any solution to let data array being the resource for admin report?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing, I cannot use non-collection format (array, object) to fullfill admin grid,
but I found [this plugin](https://github.com/degdigital/magento2-customreports) using raw SQL to make a collection which is more flexible.

If you are annoying with this issue also, hope this can helps you too.